# Save specific file type as attachment with received date time

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

1. save only images to a folder i.e .jpg .jpeg .gif .png
2. Include the received date
3. rename all saved image filetypes to ".jpg"

I have most of it down. It is saving files like this: test.jpeg.jpg and  test.jpg.jpg

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim strFileExtension As String

    saveFolder = "C:\emails\"
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    strFileExtension = ".jpg"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName & strFileExtension
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Also, if you rename a gif or a png to a jpg, you are going to have problems. They need to be converted to the format, not just named.

Comment: Hi JNevil.

Thanks for the reply.
Lets scrap .png and .gif then. Its not as important.

1. How do i make this script only download .jpeg and .jpg?
2. how do i make it save as .jpg 

at the moment it is saving files like this:
test.jpeg.jpg

test.jpg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim strFileExtension As String
    Dim strSaveFileName as string

    saveFolder = "C:\emails\"
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    strFileExtension = ".jpg"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        if lcase(right(objAtt.FileName, 4)) = "jpeg" or lcase(right(obtAtt.FileName, 3) = "jpg") then

            strSaveFileName = mid(objAtt.FileName, instr(1, objAtt.FileName, ".", length(objAtt.FileName) - instr(1, obtAtt.FileName)) & strFileExtension
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & strSaveFileName
            Set objAtt = Nothing
        End if
    Next
End Sub
```

This has an added `if` statement to test for the file extension being JPG or JPEG. If it is, then it uses some string functions to grab the bits of the filename before the extension and uses that in the final `saveasfile`.

Comment: this line has a syntax error and highlights  in red..        strSaveFileName = mid(objAtt.FileName, instr(1, objAtt.FileName, ".", length(objAtt.FileName) - instr(1, obtAtt.FileName)) & strFileExtension

Comment: Sorry there should be a closing parentheses after the "."   Like `"."),  length(... `

Comment: Thanks. Tested it an no images are saved. No script errors jsut nothing happens. I removed the "\" from "c:\emails\"

Comment: Are the file names ending in "JPG" or "JPEG" instead of "jpg" or "jpeg"?

Comment: it can vary. The one i tested with was .jpg
the idea is that hundreds of people send images from different phones to this email address. The email account saves all the attachments to a folder. A program watches that folder and loads them onto my machines i invented. Brandrocket.co.za

Comment: I just changed the code slightly to convert the file suffix to lowercase before comparing to "jpg" or "jpeg" it should help. You can toss a break (f9) on that if statement and verify that it's looking at the right stuff by hovering over objatt.filename.

Comment: Thanks mate, still not working. strSaveFileName line comes up as red line and nothing is saved.